# How do you draw circles in random locations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

What would be the program code for drawing five circles in random positions in MATLAB?

Comment: challenge your favorite search with "plot circle matlab"

Comment: What would the code be to draw ONE circle at random?

Comment: Do you want a circle marker (small), or circles of a specified radius?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it simply with [SCATTER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/scatter.html) or [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) function using [RAND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rand.html) to generate random X and Y coordinates.

```
scatter(rand(5,1),rand(5,1))
```

You can draw circle also using famous [CIRCLE](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2876) function from the File Exchange.

Comment: +1 for the circle function reference. Never saw it before; nice, simple, and useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two functions together:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/pde/ug/pdecirc.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rand.html

Comment: There's an app for that, sorry a toolbox ... *Partial Differential Equation Toolbox* ...